# Structure pointer and its use

Tags: c, pointers, struct

What is the meaning of this statement in C?

where `fag` is structure and its pointer is `pat`.

```
fag *pat = &h.device[d];
d = (pat - &(h.device[0]))/(sizeof(fag)) ;
```

Comment: Second statement is useless, and might be optimized as `d = d;` hence removed (assuming that the typeof `h.device[0]` is `fag`  ....)

Comment: yes..right.. but what is meaning of 1st statement? Can you explain me clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fag *pat = &h.device[d];
```

takes the address od the `d`th element of the said array.

It can be used to ease the access to it.

If I do

```
d = (pat - &(h.device[0]))/(sizeof(fag));
```

where I don't have access to the original `d`, I get the index of the given entry, in the said array.

It takes the difference from "our" pointer to the original one.

If I see it right, the division by `sizeof fag` is wrong - the difference is already in terms of `fag` size. Besides, `&(h.device[0])` is exactly the same as `h.device`, so

```
d = pat - h.device;
```

should be the right thing. ([Thank you, WhozCraig.](/questions/21400682/structure-pointer-and-its-use/21400965#comment32281194_21400965))

Comment: You're quite correct on the usage of `sizeof()` in the second snippet. It should not be there, and +1 on the answer. Its more intuitive for me to simply use something like `d = (pat - h.device)`, but I realize the pointer-type purists have issues with it and I acknowledge that as warranted. I just can't seem to edge that C-ism out of me.

Comment: @ glglgl Thanx ! But how difference comes to be in terms of  fag  size?

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right with that simplified syntax. Why should there be issues?

Comment: @glglgl its a type-thing. the type is technically `fag (*)[n]` for whatever `n` is, not simply `fag *` (unless `device` is actually a pointer, which I don't know since I can't see it).

Comment: @user3243408 its pointer arithmetic in reverse. If `p1` is a pointer into some array sequence (dynamic or not), then just like `p2 = p1 + N` will properly give an address advanced `N*sizeof(type)` bytes, the reverse is true, which makes sense. In essence , `(p2 - p1) = N`. Many don't think of it that way, but its true and it works. Play around with it. you'll see. Use simple types like `int` and `int *` and print the addresses using `printf("%p\n", ptr)`. Then do the math on paper.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's right, but an array type decays into the appropriate pointer type in all but 3 or 4 cases. It is perfectly valid to make use of that.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Oh yes!! I tried.. And its working.. (p2 -p1 = N). So it means that compiler internally handles it?  Because it directly divides it by sizeof(type) !

Comment: @glglgl can you tell me : Compiler internally handles it? Because it directly divides it by sizeof(type) !

Comment: @Fagun Yes - as said: that's how pointer arithmetics work. Assume for simplicity you have `uint16_t p`. Then `p2 = p + 1` lets `p2` point 2 bytes ahead of `p`, and `p2 - p` shows the difference in terms of elements (1), not in terms of bytes (2).

Answer (score 0):

One possible use of a structure pointer might be that if you want to change the members of a struct in a function, you have to pass the struct's address.

Comment: But i think,here is not the case !